# json.loads() function causing Unterminated string exception

Tags: python, json

I am following a tutorial series to create a chatbot with python and tensorflow here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9os9uQJqDbI&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdc2k5dwtDTyT9aCja0on8j&index=5

When I run the code like he does near the end of the video (pt. 5), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\camer\OneDrive\Desktop\Datasets\ChatBot\chatbot_database.py", line 101, in <module>
    row = json.loads(row)
  File "C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 368 (char 367)
```

My code is almost exactly the same as is the video, and I am using the RC_2015-05.bz2 file from [here](http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/)

I am using python 3.6 on windows 10, and I have also tried it on 3.5.

Is there a mistake in the code, or is there something wrong with the file? Also, I saw a post that said the files could be corrupted. How can I tell if that's the case, and if so, what should I do?

Thanks for any help

Edit:
Here is the part of the code that is causing the error:

```
for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            comment_id = row['name']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
```

f is the file.

Comment: Please, include the code in your question.

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL?

Comment: You need to provide the relevant code snippet that you are referring to in your question.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but you *did* unbzip that file first, right?

Comment: This is almost certainly an error with the contents of `row`.  It is saying that the parser found a `"` in the 368th character and did not find an end quote in a valid context

Comment: Yes, I did unzip the file.

Comment: The exception suggests that your JSON file is messed up. It's not a problem with your code, but with your data.

Comment: Do you know what is wrong with it or how I could fix it?

Comment: The message is clear, it has unbalanced double quotes.

Comment: Paste the value of `row` into jsonlint.com.